# Proving $2\cosh 2x+ \sinh x = 5$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have been sitting on this question for quite some time and I haven't been able to prove this identity. Please anybody who can help me here. I am new to hyperbolics.

$$2\cosh 2x+ \sinh x = 5$$

I got the answer $\ln(2)$. But I don't want to solve the question is how to prove.

Comment: *How* did you get the answer $\ln(2)$?

Comment: That is not an identity. Are you solving for $x$ instead?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYo9miq6LUWXOBGgQMWsefE0TarqMnd-/view

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/246513/john-wayland-bales

Consider the equality sign as congruency sign and then try to prove it. I spent quite some time on finding ways to do it, but it didn't click. I solved it and I don't think for any value of x it will give 5 as I got a solid value of x = ln(2) for which the equality stands true. I don't understand how could I prove this.

Comment: I get  $\cosh(2 \ln2)+\sinh(\ln2)=\dfrac{4+\frac14}2+\dfrac{2-\frac12}2=\dfrac{23}8$

Comment: Can anyone look over this.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYo9miq6LUWXOBGgQMWsefE0TarqMnd-/view

Comment: Now that the question is edited, I get $\color{red}2\cosh(2 \ln2)+\sinh(\ln2)=4+\frac14+\dfrac{2-\frac12}2\check=5$

Comment: @HarisRashid: As John mentions, this is not an identity: substituting $x=0$ gives $2\cdot 1+0=5$, which isn't usually considered true. :) In any case, you should include the work you've done in the question itself; comments are easily overlooked. (Also, a link to some file on a Google drive is problematic, since it isn't permanent. There's also a danger that you're linking to malware.) Telling as much as you know about a question helps answerers tailor their responses to best assist you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or duplicating your effort.

Comment: @Blue: Thanks for correction, I am actually new to these forums. I am quite surprised how fast professional help comes. Really motivated to discuss more questions. Sure I will do all you have suggested from now on. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If $e^x=a$,

$$10=2(a^2+a^{-2})+a-a^{-1}=2(y^2+2)+y,$$ where $y=a-a^{-1}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $y^2+y-8$ does not factor over the rationals.

Comment: @John, you are correct

Comment: Yes thats what I am thinking. It gives complex roots

Comment: Note:  OP just edited question, putting $2$ in front of $\cosh$

Comment: Yeah that was by mistake. Now the question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Write $s:=\sinh x$ so $$0=2(2s^2+1)+s-5=4s^2+s-3=(s+1)(4s-3)\implies s\in\{-1,\,\tfrac34\}.$$From $\operatorname{arsinh}s=\ln(s+\sqrt{s^2+1})$, these values of $s$ give $x\in\{\ln(\sqrt{2}-1),\,\ln 2\}$.